# permanent bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I have a task to write application, that will connect to not-mobile-phone device by blue tooth and this device will send some data every second(some statistics) and device shouldn't disconnect after sanding one batch of data. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you saying that your socket closes after each data transfer?  Because that shouldn't be happening in the first place.

Comment: I'm not familiar with bluetooth on android, so I just need some quick answer, is it possible and link for some sample

Answer (score 2):

If you open up a bluetooth socket connection, it will stay open as long as you hold the reference to it and neither end closes.

A simple example is the [Bluetooth Chat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) example.  It shows how to connect two phones, but it also shows how to maintain the connection and check if it's still alive.

Also, in Android, it can be sometimes tricky to maintain the reference because `Activities` restart on orientation changes.  Generally people put it in a `Service` and send data that way.  It's a quick and easy way of maintaining the connection.