# Working of bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am working on a project where we are developing a product which has two main components namely :- An android tablet and a PCB(contains an RN 42 Bluetooth chip).The product has few physical buttons which is connected to the PCB.

Working:Whenever any of the physical buttons on the product is pressed,the PCB will send 1 byte of data(representing the particular button) via Bluetooth to the android device(wherein its received and an activity is invoked)

My doubts:

1) When two devices are paired and a Bluetooth connection is established between them,then will this Bluetooth connection last/exist forever ? (if we assume that both the android device and PCB remains ON/plugged in indefinitely).

2) If point 1 is true, then internally does the Bluetooth module in both the devices send any data periodically to maintain this connection? If so ,what is this data and how often is it exchanged?

3) If point 1 is false, then do I need to send signals from my android device to the PCB module periodically to maintain the Bluetooth connection ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36990183

Answer (score 1):

Pairing information is maintained by android device forever (i.e. till unpaired purposefully), but connections needs to reestablished if lost (e.g. a device going out and reentering in the range of other device).

Bluetooth connection issues specific to Android ::

a) the orientation change issue is covered in this discussion -  [permanent bluetooth connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661195/permanent-bluetooth-connection) .

b) The onStop() event (caused due to use of buttons) issue is covered here - [Maintain bluetooth connection even after call to onStop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938871/maintain-bluetooth-connection-even-after-call-to-onstop)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info.In my case both the tablet and the PCB(containing RN-42) will always be in close physical proximity.In that case are you saying that once both of them are paired(and assuming no power failure),then both will have a live bluetooth connection forever?